# Google Geocoding and Autocomplete do not return the same number of results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-geocoder

For the same address entered by the user in the address input, the google **Autocomplete API** on the front-end (with javacript) returns **a single result** and thus **a single choice for the user**.
Whereas the **Geocoder API** on the back-end (PHP) returns **two different results**.

I have a back-end validation that gets the address entered by the user thanks to Autocomplete and checks this address with geocoder. If I have no results with the geocoder or more than one result (which is my case, since I get 2 results with the geocoder), I throw an exception.

This is an issue for me because my validation with the geocoder should be able to rely on the Autocomplete.

Please find below my extra explanation

**Explanation:**

I have a form on my website, where the user enters his address in an address input. This input uses the google Autocomplete API with javascript as follow.

```
var addressAutocompleteGoogleMaps = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($myInputJqueryElement[0], {
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'},
    types: ['geocode']
});

addressAutocompleteGoogleMaps.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var addressAutocompleteSelectedAddress = $myInputJqueryElement.val();
    var autocompletionFormattedAddress = addressAutocompleteGoogleMaps.getPlace().formatted_address;
    $myInputJqueryElement.val(autocompletionFormattedAddress);

    // After having changed my form value to the formatted_address, I submit the form.
});
```

Now if the user enters the following address

```
21bis Rue Claude Bernard, 75005 Paris, France
```

(as you can see there is a space missing between the `21` and the `bis` in the address), well on the front end-side, **google Autocomplete seems to recognize this address and gives the user a single unique choice**. As you can see below:

[image]

if I perform a `console.log(addressAutocompleteGoogleMaps.getPlace());`, I can see a single result in my console, with the following attributes:

```
place_id: "ChIJzX6RiOtx5kcRCaog3ti3QTs"
formatted_address: "21bis Rue Claude Bernard, 75005 Paris, France"
geometry: {location: _.P, viewport: _.Q}
```

But in my back-end, I use the geocoder service of Google and do not tolerate more than one result from the API.

If I use the same address as the `formatted_address` of the Autocomplete result on the front-end, which is `21bis Rue Claude Bernard, 75005 Paris, France`, and I submit it to the geocoder API on my back-end with to this URL

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=myKey&language=fr&region=fr&address=21bis+Rue+Claude+Bernard%2C+75005+Paris%2C+France
```

(as you can see in the URL parameters, there is no space between `21` and `bis` because the submitted address by my user, based on the choice of Google Autocomplete does not contain a space either)

I get the following results from the geocoder:

[image]

As you can see I get two results with the geocoder from the address `21bis Rue Claude Bernard, 75005 Paris, France`.

But I only get one result with the Autocomplete.

Event the place_ids are not the same. With the autocomplete API, the place_id is `ChIJzX6RiOtx5kcRCaog3ti3QT`. But with the geocode API, I get two other place_ids, which are `ChIJVeIPVu9x5kcRPHRX59oID5M` and `ChIJG9djYOxx5kcR1JtnnCReAxU`.

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE**

**Why does the Google Geocoder not return the same results as the Google Autocomplete? How can I solve my problem?**

**I want:**

**- either my Autocomplete to return the same 2 results as my geocoder**

**- either my geocoder to return a single result, the same as the Autocomplete**

(ps: And by the way, I tried typing the same address on the online geocoder of Google on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro and I also get a single address as you can see below. So how come my back-end usage of the geocoding API still return 2 results??)

[image]

Comment: Autocomplete and the geocoder are two different services, with different purposes. One uses the Places API, the other doesn't (necessarily).  There is no reason they should behave the way you are expecting.

Comment: 1) *Each place ID can refer to only one place, but a single place can have more than one place ID*. This is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#multiple-ids). 2) Why do you need that extra validation and why do you do it with the geocoder?